# Import CSV into MySQL via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

I would like to import an CSV File with looks like.:

```
"Berichtname:"  "Test2" 

"Berichtstatus:"    "Die Berichterstellung ist erfolgreich beendet."    


"Name"  "Wert"  "Einheit"   "Objektbeschreibung"    "Zustand"   "Typ"   "L/S"   "Parameter" "Min"   "Max"   
"B4'TAA3'MtEF'AFGl05'CumEg" "99,7"  "kWh"   "kum. Wirkenergie"  ""  "Real Zahl" "5/3"   "PrVal" "-340282200000000000000000000000000000000.00"   "340282200000000000000000000000000000000.00"    
"B4'TZ03'MtrEl'MtrEl05'Pwr" "10"    "kW"    "Wirkleistung"  "S" "Real Zahl" "5/3"   "PrVal" "-340282200000000000000000000000000000000.00"   "340282200000000000000000000000000000000.00"
```

I have tried to import the file, but without any success.. What I want is to skip the first 6 Lines and just add the last two lines.

Can anyone please help me?

```
<?php 

//database connection details
$connect = mysql_connect('XXXXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXXXX','XXXXXXXXXXX');

if (!$connect) {
 die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysql_error());
 }

//your database name
$cid =mysql_select_db('XXXXXXXXXXX',$connect);

// path where your CSV file is located
define('CSV_PATH','');

// Name of your CSV file
$csv_file = CSV_PATH . "export.csv";

if (($getfile = fopen($csv_file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
        $data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",");
        while (($data = fgetcsv($getfile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
         $num = count($data); 
         for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
             $result = $data; 
             $str = implode(",", $result); 
             $slice = explode(",", $str);
             $col1 = $slice[0]; 
             $col2 = $slice[1];
             $col3 = $slice[2]; 

// SQL Query to insert data into DataBase

$query = "INSERT INTO daten(sensor,wert)
VALUES('".$col1."','".$col2."')";

$s=mysql_query($query, $connect ); 
     }
   } 
  }

echo "File data successfully imported to database!!"; 
mysql_close($connect); 
?>
```

Comment: how did you try to import this? can you post your php script :)

Comment: [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) has an option to `IGNORE 6 LINES`; so what's the problem?

Comment: Why are you imploding and then exploding your data for each row?

Comment: The tab between the vars.

Comment: As it's a tab-separated file, use `fgetcsv` with "\t" delimiter rather than the default ",", then you don't need to implode and explode again

Comment: Kind of anoying, changed it but now the vars are in one MySQL field. Could you rewrite the code? That would be cool dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the Complete tutorial For Csv to MySql](http://www.johnboy.com/blog/tutorial-import-a-csv-file-using-php-and-mysql)